# Json encoding doesn't display comma

Tags: php, arrays, json

In my API I set in the core script this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

when an error is handled I return this:

```
return json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => "No content."));
```

The problem is that I get an invalid json, how you can see in the image:

[image]

How you can see the json is invalid, should be:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "No content."
}
```

I also tried to insert `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` but I got the same result. What is wrong? In the `Raw` I get a correct encoding:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused - you shouldnt get the comma in the json as its used as a separator to the array function?

Comment: @FreudianSlip `json_encode()` should insert the comma automatically, the `,` in array is just for separate the key.

Comment: If you dump the array before you json_encode it, what do you get?

Comment: json(encode): `string(60) "{"success":false,"message":"No content."}"` without encode: `array(2) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["message"]=>
  string(30) "No content."
}`

Comment: You're right.. I've just tried it but cannot get it to fail.. I always get the comma.

Comment: @FreudianSlip so in your system working? It's too strange this situation

Comment: Yeah, works fine for me - even at the command line .. looks like your computer is haunted :) .. sorry i coudlnt help.   sudo php /var/www/html/t.php
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "No content."
}%

Comment: @FreudianSlip other hints for encoding it?

Comment: Except from building the JSON yourself .. no.. I have to admit defeat. I cant find anywhere else that has a report of the same problem, although I am still looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw response is fine. So...

Whatever GUI you're using, it just doesn't display the comma between the fields. But it's there.